# How much would a 3 foot tall person weigh

Tags: creature-design, humans

I'm trying to worldbuild and one of my creatures is a 3 foot tall humanoid and I have no idea what they should weigh.

Does anyone know how much they would weigh or a math equation I could use to figure it out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Given that there are easily tens of millions of 3 foot tall humanoids on earth have you done any research into the average height of 3 year olds?

Comment: I havent done any research on 3 year olds since the character in question is an adult and toddler bones are still fusing and they dont gain muscle like an adult does. So realistically speaking it isn't the same since kids are still growing. I actually meant to put on here that using some research papers on certain human body part lengths and bmi calculators i got a semi-accurate answer sorry!

Comment: Sure, but you've got order of magnitude. Multiply by something between 0.4 and 2.5 to suit your class of hunanoid. BMI is a bad idea for non adults, IIRC, unless there's a children's curve. Try asking how much mess a 4 year old humanoid can make!

Comment: It's easy enough to work out a rough approximation if you know an average persons wieght .. just remember there's three dimensions reducing not one when working out the volume, as with the volume so with the wieght .. if you mince them you can fit eight three proportionally equivelent three foot people into the same size cube you can fit a minced six foot person and they'll each weigh an eighth of that six foot persons wieght  this is really just a straight math problem.

Comment: There is a number of real people with dwarfism who are 3 feet or smaller. They are built differently than people of closer to average height though, with proportionally bigger heads and shorter limbs. If your humanoids are going to be built like that, just research the typical weight of such people. If you want them to have the same proportions as people of regular height, just scaled down, you can just scale down the weight of an average person.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.  If this is a question that shouldn't get an answer here, vote to close; else answer in answers.

Comment: I apologize for voting to close your question and will gladly retract my vote if you provide the necessary clarifications. Here's the problem: People/creatures come in all shapes and sizes. Muscle density, bone structure... fat... there isn't a single equation (although @ZeissIkon's answer is a good start) that accommodates everything. Can you describe your subject in greater detail? How many arms and legs? What's different about them compared to humans? Is the subject physically fit or has it been playing video games and snacking on ice cream for the last year? Thanks!

Comment: Also, when responding to comments please note that if you use the At-symbol and the users name, the system will automatically notify them of your response. So should you wish to respond to me, remember to include @JBH in the message. You can tag only one user at a time like this.

Comment: ***LADIES AND GENTLEMEN:*** When you see as the first comment to any post a complaint by the **Community Bot** - *you shouldn't be answering the question* either below or in comments (which you should never do anyway). When the question is so ambiguous or lacks so much detail that the Bot gets involved, you should set aside your belief that you can assume/guess/telepathically-figure-out what the OP is talking about and instead post comments helping the OP write a better question.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the same proportions as a "normal" human (**bad assumption, see below**), weight is proportional to volume, hence to the *cube* of height -- that is, a creature with double the linear dimension (height) would weigh 2^3 = 8 times as much, so your three foot dwarf would weigh about one eighth what a six foot human would.

However, notice the size of a mouse's legs relative to its body, vs. the size of an elephant's.  Strength of limbs scales only as the *square* of height (it's based on cross sectional area rather than volume), so the larger the creature, the relatively thicker its limbs need to be in comparison to its height.

There are three ways a race evolved (or created) to be half as tall might deal with this: they might weigh more, by carrying additional muscle, making them stronger relative to their size and weight than the prototypical 6 foot human (or by running strongly to fat, perhaps as a store against famine or hibernation); they might have skinnier legs (and likely arms) relative to their height, breaking their proportions and making them more similar to a monkey or small ape in terms of body appearance; or (if created rather than evolved) they might maintain human proportions and simply have stronger legs relative to the rest of their body (the difference likely wouldn't make them incredible jumpers, but they might do well at power lifting).

Answer (score 2):

Here is Commodore Nutt

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_Nutt

[image: commodore nutt]

He was an American entertainer and showman and a contemporary of General Tom Thumb.
Nutt was 29 inches tall and 25 pounds.  [General Tom Thumb was 40 inches (1 metre) and 70 pounds (32 kg).](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Charles-Stratton)

I was a little skeptical of the 25 pounds for Commodore Nutt.  But Google gave me this

[image: nutt weight]

from [The Normal Higher Arithmetic](https://books.google.com/books?id=-2EXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=how+much+did+commodore+nutt+weigh&source=bl&ots=G5zRbMNktI&sig=ACfU3U1TvHy6Bt47BNO7_DSn4mn1y6geng&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivtoCOtJT6AhVMMEQIHRh_ApAQ6AF6BAgnEAM#v=onepage&q=how%20much%20did%20commodore%20nutt%20weigh&f=false) an 1877 math textbook.  Dang, Google!

So there is a fair range of weights for humans around your desired height.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose they are similar to humans living in an earth-like environment.

BMI = mass (kg)/ height2 (m) = 703 × mass (lbs)/ height2 (in)

As told [here](https://www.calculator.net/bmi-calculator.html):

Healthy BMI range is 18.5 kg/m2 - 25 kg/m2.

Therefore, healthy range of weight for a 3 feet tall person is 34.1 lbs - 46.1 lbs.

Comment: BMI is used for convenience but doesn't scale well outside the average adult range.  Corpulence Index is better (but still not perfect) for small people, and gives a range of roughly 17.5 - 21.5 lb for 3 foot adult.